# ViewPager tries to load all fragments available even if i set offset limit to 1 which results in GC and blank screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments, garbage-collection, android-viewpager

I have implmented ViewPager whose adapter is of type FragmentStatePagerAdapter and I have overrided getItem method which returns Fragment. I have only one fragment class only input which is url to show image differs and have layout heirarchy which is bit complex.

I have set my ViewPager offset limit to 1 as follows but i put logs to check that getItem and getSize of adapter getting called always.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

As a result when viewpager is loading GC runs and blank screen comes for a time which is annoying.

Following is my adapter code:

```
private class CategoryViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public CategoryViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

            super(fm);
            Log.i("Blank", "getItem Call in Fragment Super Call");

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int currentPosition) {
            Log.i("Blank", "getItem Call in Fragment");
            FullScreenFragment fragment = FullScreenFragment
                    .newInstance(fragments.get(currentPosition));
            Log.i("Blank", "getItem Call in Fragment Finished");
            return fragment;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.i("Blank", "getItem Call in Fragment Size");
            return fragments.size();
        }

    }
```

How to avoid blank screen when viewpager with many items is getting loaded? If i open fragment stand alone it loads very fast so complexity of hierarchy is fine.

Please help,